# Show password eye icon is not visible in Google Chrome

Tags: html, typescript, google-chrome, input, passwords

I have defined password field in form with html/Typescript

```html
<input type="password" class="form-control input-left" formControlName="currentPassword" placeholder="Current Password" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" />
```

I can see show password eye icon on right side inside box in Edge. But I dont see it in Chrome.
Do I need to manually add code code to create this eye symbol or how to make it visible in Chrome?

Comment: It's probably a "feature" in edge or with help from a plugin/extension (I don't see it with Chrome or Firefox)

Comment: Ok, so i need to add manual code to display eye icon in Chrome, may be.

Comment: there might be libraries that already do that for you; not sure what you might be using for the UI, I'd start with those

Comment: I also just tested with Edge and do not see the icon as described.  This could be a browser setting (on your computer only)

Comment: I also don't see the eye icon on my new version of Chrome. Is this a security feature. I can't live without it.